# pivot table in pandas with a subtraction function on all possible combinations

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have a dataframe that looks something like

```
Strike. Strike2 Price
15000.  15000.  100
15100.  15100.  150
15200.  15200.  170
```

I want to create a matrix like df such that the output looks like

```
Strike. 15000.  15100.  15200.
15000.   0.      50.     120
15100.  -50      0.      20
15200.  -170.    -20.    0
```

Its essentially looking to compute the difference in prices at all strikevalues.
Can you help how i can achieve this efficiently please.

I think i need to use aggfunc, but somehow not getting the desired result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `pivot_table` directly, you should use [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) broadcasting:

```
a = df['Price'].to_numpy()
out = pd.DataFrame(a-a[:, None], columns=df['Strike2'], index=df['Strike.'])
```

Output:

```
Strike2  15000.0  15100.0  15200.0
Strike.                           
15000.0        0       50       70
15100.0      -50        0       20
15200.0      -70      -20        0
```

Comment: What can i do if i only need the upper triangle of the matrix ?
for eg: all the records below 0 can be deleted

Comment: Combine it with [`np.triu`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.triu.html): `np.triu(a-a[:, None])`

Comment: this is great, thanks a lot.
I believe we cannot just make the lower part of dataframe disappear :). it will have to stay at 0s it seems?
That will be more of presentation i suppose :)

Comment: You can if you convert to strings and use an empty string to mask the lower triangle